# Show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t+x) \ dW(x) =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=-x(n)}^{x(n)}f(t+\frac{k}{n})(W(\frac{k+1}{n})-W(\frac{k}{n})). $

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

I had this question up a few hours ago but it had lots of views but no answers, so I figured my question was bad and I did not provide enough information, so here is a better question I hope.

In my book it says:

> Let $\{W(t)\}_{t\in{\mathbb{R}}}$ be a Wiener-process and
>   $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function such that
>   $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)^2 \ dx < \infty.$ It's not hard to show
>   that the following integral is well defined.
>
> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t+x) \
>  dW(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\sum_{k=-x(n)}^{x(n)}f\left(t+\frac{k}{n}\right)\left(W\left(\frac{k+1}{n}\right)-W\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)\right],$$
>
> where $\pm x(n)$ should satisfy
>   $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x(n)/n=\infty.$

I really do not agree with the authors of this book. It does not seem easy to show the above.

Later I'm given that

$$f(t)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    1-t^2 & \text{for} & |t| \leq 1 \\
    0 & \text{for} & |t| > 1 \\
  \end{array} , \quad t\in[0,10]
\right.$$

This $f$ will somehow put constraints on my $k$, but I don't seem to succeed no matter what I do. I tried to set

$$\left|t+\frac{k}{n}\right|> 1$$

and solve for $k$ but this led me nowhere.

**Questions:**

1. How to show this?
2. What are my $x(n)?$ How do I mathematically find these?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Using $g$ for a dummy variable of integration and $\{g(n)\}$ for a sequence is confusing. I think $\{g(n)\}$ is supposed to be any sequence of real numbers such that $\frac {g(n)} n \to \infty$ and it is better to change the variable of integration to some symbol other  than  $g$.

Comment: How would you propose to change it? $g(n)$ is just what it says, a function of $n$ and not a sequence of numbers. I literally quoted my book.

Comment: I am just suggesting that you could change $g$ in all the integrals to some other variable, say $x$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy - Done. I hope it's less confusing now and that someone in here can help. I don't understand, I've seen much more advanced math in this forum but somehow noone seems to be able to even attempt an answer on this one. Am I being unclear or is this just so hard?

Comment: In which sense is the limit supposed to exist? (in $L^2$, in probability,....)

Comment: I'm not sure, they don't specify that at all.